# Joomla 2.5 template jQuery upgrade

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla, joomla-template

In my custom template there isnt any refrences to jquery. But still in source code under head tag joomla is loading

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am just wondering where is it getting this to load? I have checked the head.php, but its not pointing to any jQuery libraries. Where am i able to change this to point to jquery-1.9.js. Head is also loading some other javascript files, but i think those are Joomlas some standards to be loaded. Is there a place some where in admin panel where i can change these, because in the code i haven't find the suitable place or way.

index.php:

```
<head>
<jdoc:include type="head" />

<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Check all the module's, plugin's and component's configurations, may be one of them loading this. Because many extension provide this configuration like you want to load jQuery or not.

Comment: If it's not coming from the template, then it will be coming from an extension, most likely a module or component. I would not remove it from the extension though as they have included it for obvious reasons